# Downloading to RAM instead of External Storage in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager, download-manager

in an android app, im using Android's builtin download manager for downloading files. but it need External storage permission. i cant set this permission right now. is there any way to download to device RAM instead of External Storage? my problem is Permissions...

i do like this:

```
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: just so you know -- The download manager uses system generated file names and saves all files in the shared download cache.

You can also choose where to save the file. But, you can only save it in the external storage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes-  don't use DownloadManager.  Just make a direct HTTP request for the item, and read the result from the response. You'll lose a lot of features that DownloadManager gives you (like automated restarts) unless you rewrite them yourself though.